# How to turn off redirection from 'domain.com/login' to 'domain.com/wp-login.php'

Tags: php, redirect, login

I want to install something different than wordpress under 'mydomain.com/login', but WordPress automatically redirecting this link '/login' to '/wp-login.php'.

Where can I turn off this redirection?

Comment: This question is almost similar to what you are asking!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976781/redirecting-wordpresss-login-register-page-to-a-custom-login-registration-page?lq=1

Comment: Please do a bit more search on this site and I am sure you will find a solution for this problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [`canonical.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/canonical.php) you will notice that the `wp_redirect_admin_locations` function is hooked very late-- [at priority 1000](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/canonical.php#L536). This means that just about any function hooked to `redirect_canonical` runs before this one. So, conditionally remove `wp_redirect_admin_locations` from the `template_redirect` hook.

```
add_action(
  'template_redirect', 
  function() {
    $requ = untrailingslashit($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (site_url('login','relative') === $requ ){
      remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the findings of [“login” in permalink redirects to wp-login.php wp3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241408/login-in-permalink-redirects-to-wp-login-php-wp3-6)

## Disable "/login" redirect

As already stated there the relevant code is located at the very end in */wp-includes/canonical.php*

You need to **remove the default "wp_redirect_admin_locations"** and **replace it with a slightly modified custom version**. Add this to your function.php file.

```
function custom_wp_redirect_admin_locations() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( ! ( is_404() && $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) )
        return;

    $admins = array(
        home_url( 'wp-admin', 'relative' ),
        home_url( 'dashboard', 'relative' ),
        home_url( 'admin', 'relative' ),
        site_url( 'dashboard', 'relative' ),
        site_url( 'admin', 'relative' ),
    );
    if ( in_array( untrailingslashit( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), $admins ) ) {
        wp_redirect( admin_url() );
        exit;
    }

    $logins = array(
        home_url( 'wp-login.php', 'relative' )
    );
    if ( in_array( untrailingslashit( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), $logins ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login' ) );
        exit;
    }
}

function remove_default_login_redirect() {
    remove_action('template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000);
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
}

add_action('init','remove_default_login_redirect');
```

## Why this might not even be necessary

Also you should be aware that the redirect only applies if there is nothing else at /login. As soon as e.g. you create a page /login the redirect doesn't apply any more. (See */wp-includes/canonical.php:553* for where this happens.

Comment: The best working script for this I have found! Thanks!